# Makefile runs over C file twice

Tags: gcc, makefile

I have two files: assign1.c and ports.h.

FYI: I am using avr-gcc.

I built the following makefile, which I also use for another project (and other TARGET) where it works fine.

```
TARGET = assign2
LIB=
INCLUDE=ports.h
CFLAGS =-mmcu=atmega32 -Wall
CC = avr-gcc
SRC= $(TARGET).c
OBJ= $(SRC:.c=.o)

OBJCOPY = avr-objcopy
FORMAT  = ihex

MSG_COMPILING = Compiling:
MSG_LINKING = Linking:
MSG_FLASH = Creating load file for flash:

all:elf hex

elf: $(TARGET).elf
hex: $(TARGET).hex

%.hex: %.elf
    @echo $(MSG_FLASH) $@
    @echo 
    $(OBJCOPY) -O $(FORMAT) -R .eeprom $< $@
    $(RM) *.elf $(TARGET)
    @echo 

%.elf: $(OBJ) $(LIB)
    @echo $(MSG_LINKING) $@
    @echo 
    $(CC)  $(CFLAGS)  $^ -o $@
    @echo 

%.o: $(SRC) $(INCLUDE)
    @echo $(MSG_COMPILING) $<
    @echo 
    $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) -c $<
    @echo 

.PHONY : clean

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *.hex *.elf $(TARGET)
```

The terminal prints the following output.

```
C:\Project>make
Compiling: assign2.c

avr-gcc  -mmcu=atmega32 -Wall -c assign2.c
In file included from assign2.c:8:
c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/util/delay.h:90:3: warning: #warnin
g "Compiler optimizations disabled; functions from <util/delay.h> won't work as
designed"

Linking: assign2.elf

avr-gcc  -mmcu=atmega32 -Wall  assign2.o -o assign2.elf

Compiling: assign2.c

avr-gcc  -mmcu=atmega32 -Wall -c assign2.c
In file included from assign.c:8:
c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/util/delay.h:90:3: warning: #warnin
g "Compiler optimizations disabled; functions from <util/delay.h> won't work as
designed"

avr-gcc   elf.o assign2.elf   -o elf
avr-gcc: elf.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [elf] Error 1
rm assign2.o

C:\Project>
```

For some reason it seems to compile the first file, a second time and doing so crashes.

Can anyone correct me on my errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your pattern rules.  You are writing pattern rules like this (after make expands the variables):

```
%.o: assign2.c ports.h
```

What this rule tells make is that ANY target it wants to build that matches the `%.o` pattern, can be built by compiling `assign2.c`.  That's obviously not true: this rule build exactly one target: `assign2.o`.

So make reads your makefile and wants to build a file named `elf`.  It sees that `elf` depends on `$(TARGET).elf`, so it builds that (that's the first compile and link, that works).  Then make wants to build `elf` itself.  You haven't declared it to be .PHONY, so make assumes it might be a real target.

Make looks through its built-in rules to find one that will let it build `elf`, and it finds a built-in rule:  `% : %.o` which it can use to compile a program from a `.o` file with the same prefix.  So now for target `elf` make wants to try to build a file `elf.o`.  Oho!  It sees there's a pattern rule that lets it build any `.o` file based on the `assign2.c` source file, so it runs that rule (that's the second compile) expecting it to build `elf.o`... which it doesn't, obviously.

Then make runs the built-in link recipe, using `elf.o` which doesn't exist, and fails.

The solution to your problem is two things:

First, you should always declare all your makefile targets that you don't actually want to build as .PHONY so make won't try to build them:

```
.PHONY: all elf hex
```

Second, you should never use pattern rules where the prerequisite is not also a pattern (this can be useful in certain very specific situations, but not in general).  You should either change those pattern rules to explicit rules:

```
assign2.elf: $(OBJ) $(LIB)
        ...

$(OBJ): $(SRC) $(INCLUDE)
        ...
```

Or make them into full pattern rules by using the pattern in the prerequisites list as well:

```
%.elf : %.obj $(LIB)
        ...

%.o: %.c $(INCLUDE)
        ...
```